# use wildcard in nginx configuration server name

Tags: nginx, configuration, server-name

i wanna use wild card in nginx configuration server name

example)

```
server_name m.*.domain.com;
```

but it shows

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid server name or wildcard "m.*.domain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

is there possible way to solve this problem ?

Comment: You could use a *regular expression*. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Answer (score 5):

For future questions, you can also look here:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Wildcards in nginx are admitted in the way of *.example.com or www.example.* , but not in www.*.example.com or  www.*example.com, those are invalid.

What you can do, is use a Regular Expression like this:

```
server_name ~^www\..+\.example\.org$
```

or

```
server_name ~^w.*\.example\.org$
```

Which in your case would be something like:

```
server_name ~^m.*\.domain\.com$
```

Do have in mind that Regular Expressions are the same as the ones accepted by Perl (the programming language).

Comment: The space between `~` and `^www...` is incorrect and will probably lead to an error like `[emerg] empty regex in server name "~"`